# How to hide object using both a click and the escape key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, overlay, user-experience

I would like to add the functionality to both click outside of this box and also use the escape key. How would I go about doing that?

Here's working code that gets the element to hide with a click:

```
 $('.player-wrapper, .player .close').click(function(){
var source = $('.brand-video').find('iframe').attr('src');
  $('.brand-video').find('iframe').attr('src', '');
  $('.brand-video').find('iframe').attr('src', source);
$('.player-wrapper').hide().css('opacity', 0);
$('html').css('overflow', 'visible');
$('.player').css({
  transform:'scale(0,0)',
  '-webkit-transform':'scale(0,0)',
  '-moz-transform':'scale(0,0)',
  '-o-transform':'scale(0,0)'
}).hide();
$('.player-wrapper').removeClass('video');
});
```

How do I add the escape key to this? Thanks for your help! Here's the site: https://icelandicforyes.com/home-storefront/

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this.

```
var KEYCODE_ESC = 27;

function hideVideo() {
    var source = $('.brand-video').find('iframe').attr('src');
    $('.brand-video').find('iframe').attr('src', '');
    $('.brand-video').find('iframe').attr('src', source);
    $('.player-wrapper').hide().css('opacity', 0);
    $('html').css('overflow', 'visible');
    $('.player').css({
        transform:'scale(0,0)',
        '-webkit-transform':'scale(0,0)',
        '-moz-transform':'scale(0,0)',
        '-o-transform':'scale(0,0)'
    }).hide();

    $('.player-wrapper').removeClass('video');
}

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == KEYCODE_ESC) { hideVideo(); } 
});

$('.player-wrapper, .player .close').click(function(){ hideVideo(); });
```